# autofill.js typeError. I don't know where to start fixing this

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, autofill

I've randomly started receiving the following error any time I reload my web browser while working on a small project.

Troubleshooting seems difficult as I am unfamiliar with the file 'autofill.js'. Does anyone know what this is or how to resolve? It doesn't seem to have any adverse affect on the functionality of my project. However, just appears in the console as an error.

Error:

```
autofill.js:10733 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encrypt')
at 45 (autofill.js:10733:33)
at o (autofill.js:1:265)
at autofill.js:1:316
at 44../captureDdgGlobals.js (autofill.js:10579:49)
at o (autofill.js:1:265)
at autofill.js:1:316
at 54.../../../packages/device-api/index.js (autofill.js:11616:25)
at o (autofill.js:1:265)
at autofill.js:1:316
at 56../android.transport.js (autofill.js:11714:23)
```

Below is an image showing the autofill.js file, on the line the error links to.

[autofill.js error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsTeq.png)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue, same line: autofill.js:10733:33.

The error appears in the console, in Chrome Inspector when I load the web page.  When I hover the mouse over the file name "autofill.js:10733:33", a pop-up appears indicating the source is "chrome-extension://bkdgflcldmnnnap.../public/js/content-scripts/autofill.js"

I opened my Chrome->More Tools->Extensions folder.  There's a Search Extensions bar there, so I entered 'bkdgflc'  The extension page auto-filtered as I typed.  By the third letter there was only one extension remaining.  In my case it was "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials."  I disabled that extension and my page now loads without the error.

I know this is not a real solution but it may help figure out what's going on.